# How to assign an array of int to a corresponding property of an array of objects in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'd like to assign an array of integer values to a corresponding property of an array of objects.

```
class MyClass {
    var propint: Int = 0
    var propdbl: Double = 0.0
    var propstr: String = ""
} // MyClass

var arrint: [Int]()
var arrobj: [MyClass]()
```

One approach would be looping through the array of integers (*arrint*), and assign the value to the property *propint* of the corresponding object array element.

I'm wondering if there's a more efficient, elegant solution to this undertaking, eg. like *array.map*, and if so how this would be looking like.

--Sil68

Comment: Actually `map`, `sort` and `filter` are all loop. And they can make code clean but mostly worse performance because of safety code. Not sure there's a good way to fit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about efficient. As @Ryan said all the built in functional methods just use a loop to process the array.

Having said that, you could do something like this...

```
let updatedObjectArray = zip(arrint, arrobj).map {
    number, object -> MyClass in

    object.propint = number
    return object
}
```

You must be careful here though. By using a class (and not a struct) you will inadvertently be editing the original array.

Anyway, this will zip up both arrays, iterate them and then map them onto an array with the updated objects.

As a side note: choose better names for your variables. Even in Stack Overflow questions. Using variable names like `arrint` or `arrobj` or `propint` only do two things. Make it hard to reply to questions because auto correct wants to change them all. And make it hard to understand when reading. I know it's a property and an int (thats what the code says). The name should tell me **WHY** it's a property and an int.